# How to turn functions into one class?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to turn my functions into one class, but not sure if am doing right, while never did it before. And easy peasy examples with dogs and cars don't help really.

Appreciate if somebody can have a look at part what I've done and correct, give advice.

So here is an example of one function used in the script

Parses a page in Xing BrandManager and saves html content to a soup_followers variable

```
def xing_parse_visitors(url, EMAIL, PASSWORD, request_id, cursor):
    options = FirefoxOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    delay = 20

    #  update status in DB
    sql_start = """
                UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[Table]
                SET status = 'Started', start_time = '{}'
                WHERE request_id = '{}'
                    """.format(dt.datetime.now(), request_id)
    cursor.execute(sql_start)
    cursor.commit()

    username = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[username]')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[password]')

    username.send_keys(EMAIL)
    password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

    log_in_link = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                            '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/button'))).click()

    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup_followers = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    driver.quit()

    return soup_followers
```

What I ve done so far

I understood that if all methods share some variables, it should be an attribute
In my case, these are cursor, url, PASSWORD, EMAIL (they used in other parsers for Xing)

So I made a class Xing and a child class Parse because there are more functions will follow

```
class Xing(object):

    # Class Attribute
    cursor = cursor
    url = url
    PASSWORD = PASSWORD
    EMAIL = EMAIL

    #  Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, request_id):
        self.request_id = request_id


class Parse(Xing):
    def parse_visitors(self, url, email_xing, password_xing, cursor):
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
        driver.get(url)

        time.sleep(5)
        self.delay = 20

        #  update status in DB
        sql_start = """
                UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[Table]
                SET status = 'Started', start_time = '{}'
                WHERE request_id = '{}'
                    """.format(dt.datetime.now(), request_id)
           cursor.execute(sql_start)
           cursor.commit()


        username = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[username]')
        password = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[password]')

        username.send_keys(EMAIL)
        password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

        log_in_link = WebDriverWait(driver, self.delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
        '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/button'))).click()

        time.sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        self.soup_followers = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        driver.quit()
```

But I can't get even after googling when I should put `self.var_name` and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use class to save repeating state variables inside the object.

```py
class Xing:
    def __init__(self, cursor, url, PASSWORD, EMAIL)
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.url = url
        self.PASSWORD = PASSWORD
        self.EMAIL = EMAIL

    # Now implement all the functions below this and use the state variables from within self
    def parse_visitors(self):
        """
        You can now access all the saved state variables from self object here
        """
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
        driver.get(self.url)

        time.sleep(5)
        self.delay = 20

        #  update status in DB
        sql_start = """
                UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[Table]
                SET status = 'Started', start_time = '{}'
                WHERE request_id = '{}'
                    """.format(dt.datetime.now(), request_id)
           self.cursor.execute(sql_start)
           self.cursor.commit()


        username = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[username]')
        password = driver.find_element_by_name('login_form[password]')

        username.send_keys(self.EMAIL)
        password.send_keys(self.PASSWORD)

        log_in_link = WebDriverWait(driver, self.delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
        '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/button'))).click()

        time.sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        # save the calculated values and variables inside only if you need them access
        # outside the function.
        self.soup_followers = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: @dumbPy I don't agree with this, common attributes across all the instance are class property and hence be defined as Class attributes (outside of class methods) and attributes which might be different for each class are an instance property and hence be defined in the constructor (inside __init__ with self)

Comment: @PankajSaini I agree, but there has to be some way to set them, which is why I have put them in init. Unless the atributes are either fundamentally constant to the class or are never to be taken from user, something like say a constant you never override, or a counter you set from within the code and never want to override from user side, you cannot put it outside the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Common attributes across all the instances are class property and hence be defined as Class attributes (outside of the class methods) and attribute that might be different for each class is an instance property and hence they should be defined inside the constructor (inside init with self).

Also, instance attributes should be used iff they are used across multiple methods otherwise you can simply pass them as method arguments.

Comment: OP literally mentioned that there are other such methods, which is why he is trying to group then into a class and share the attributes. Also, the atributes are to be set from outside which is why there are being taken as arguments inside the init.